# How to prevent user accessing to my website through post in php

Tags: php, logging

I would like to block my users wanting to login from other sites.

If they use the same login form as mine on their websites and put my website url in action attribute of their form, they can log into my website since I haven't put any securities.

Is there any way that I can block them from logging into my website if they are trying to log in from external websites? I am thinking to use PHP for this. It would be appreciated if you can share php example codes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would it matter if they fill out a form on `foo.com` to log into your `bar.com`, if the end results is that they'd be logged into your site to begin with? If they have a valid username/password, what does it matter WHERE they logged in from? They'd still be logged in.

Comment: @MarcB It's important, if you do it correctly using CSRF, then you can prevent cross site submission which can be automated using a script which gatters usernames and passwords by fishing people to the site. If fishing is being used on the site as of now, there is clearly a need for this.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Phishing* unless it is a fishing game website.

Comment: @RugerSR9 Thanks, i'll try to remember that, i'm french, i didn't know exactly how to write it!

Comment: Why is this question being closed out of curiosity? Sure theres no code, but not all questions must feature code, he's looking for CSRF and didn't know how to call it, it's a perfectly valid question IMO!

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I agree, this is a valid question about a concern the OP has.  There may be duplicates (I haven't checked), but none of the close reasons so far indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, the first and foremost is to use CSRF protection. That technique will usually insert some kind of random token into the form and if the token is unexpected, you refuse to process the request.

Other ways would be to use HTTP_REFERER but that can be spoofed so it can't stop remote calling of HTTP REQUESTS through scripts, but will definitely stop simple form submission...

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. I just quickly checked out CSRF. They had an example code.

  <form action="/transfer.do" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" 
  value="OWY4NmQwODE4ODRjN2Q2NTlhMmZlYWE...
  wYzU1YWQwMTVhM2JmNGYxYjJiMGI4MjJjZDE1ZDZ...
  MGYwMGEwOA==">
  …
  </form>

I don't think this one wouldn't work either. Because people can see hidden input values if they want. They can make it identical for their login. Can you show me an example code please?

Comment: You have to use a CSRF library, the token itself always changes and it stored in the session of the user. So if the person never opened a session on your site, the token was never generated... If they connect to the site, you generate a token, save it to session and print it in the form. When the form is submitted, you compare the session and the form, matches? Fine, go on! Doesn't match? The person probably didn't use your site correctly!

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. When is that session generated? My theory is that no matter when that session is generated, the user accessing from external sites can mimic it. Because they are calling the same url as mine once they click submit button. So whatever happens under my domain is going to be the same as external accesses.

Comment: No, you are confusing sessions and application login mechanisms... A session is either started automatically by PHP if session_auto_start is activated in your PHP.ini which is rarely done. Normally, you'll want to use a SESSION_START yourself. Then, the person will receive a COOKIE to identify it's session on your site. When you show the form to the user, you generate a value that you store. This value cannot be taken by a distant script because it doesn't have the same SESSION_ID as the user will on your site. So it would have to connect to the site, get the login page

Comment: and then scrape the result for the token, save it in memory, attempt to fish a user, get the creds, submit the creds for him and then validate if it worked to save the creds in the database. This is some serious hacking attempt that is not worth it most of the time.

Comment: If you allow passing the session_id by URL (dangerous, session fixation potential hacks) then you can be hacked this way, else it is practically impossible to steal crds from your user by phishing them out. And impossible to submit because you can't set the session_id for a user if you are cross domain...

Comment: Ok. I get it. Then, how would you compare and match the token in session when the form is submitted? Are you saying that you would compare the token in session to the value in cookie? If so, users can always get that value too. Because, if they opened my website first, they retrieve the cookie value that my website generates. And then they can put the cookie value to their browser and log in from external site.

Comment: Just use a simple comparison such as: $_POST['csrf_token'] == $_SESSION['login-form.csrf-token']

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mathieu. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is preventing Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF).  OWASP has a good article on it [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).  The basic protection against this is to include a **server** side generated token in your form that is submitted along with the rest of your form data so that the request can be validated on the server side.